# What would be the integral of the zeta function or $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n^x} $?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, riemann-zeta

The zeta function is defined as:
$$ \zeta (x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {1}{n^x}  $$

Does an integral of this function exist? If it does then what would it be?

More information about zeta function can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) .

Comment: If you are happy with a sum you can put $\frac{1}{n^x} = e^{-ln(n)x}$ and integrate

Comment: This is my mathematica code for the integrated Euler Maclaurin formula for the Riemann zeta function: https://pastebin.com/9wSSSmR4 You can skip the plot and go directly to the second part for faster execution.

Comment: What do you mean precisely by *exist* ?

Comment: @MatsGranvik - Am I correct that your code only works for numerical integration? Me, and I believe the OP, are interested in integration. ( Not numerical ).

Comment: @niloderoock The full *symbolic* integral is in there. `/Log[n]` in `Sum[n^(-(1/2 + I*t))/Log[n]` indicates that it is the *symbolically* integrated version. At the end I have put `NIntegrate[ ]` which is the *numerical* integral - for comparison. The *symbolic* integral is based on the Euler-MacLaurin formula for the Riemann zeta function. `ExpIntegralEi[` is also part of the *symbolic* integral of the Euler-MacLaurin formula for the Riemann zeta function. For each term in the Euler-Maclaurin formula one gets  a segment of width one of analytic continuation for the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: @niloderoock Any Dirichlet generating function similar to $\zeta (s)$ is usually *symbolically* integrable, while $f(\zeta (s))$ where $(f(x)=\text{function})$ such as $\frac{1}{\zeta (s)}$ is not *symbolically* integrable, other than expressing the integral as a root sum which in the case of the Riemann zeta function would be a sum over the roots of the Riemann zeta function.

Comment: @niloderoock My experience with *symbolic* integrals is that whenever one has a function that is to be integrated and that involves division, then if the expression in the denominator is of higher degree than the quintic polynomial (or in some cases the septic polynomial) then Mathematica returns a root sum given that one has at least made the simplification  of transcendental functions like logarithms as fractions. When it comes to integration, of the four common methods of calculation, division is the hardest. "He who can properly define and divide is to be considered a god." - Plato.

Comment: @niloderoock "For each term added in the Euler-Maclaurin formula for the Riemann zeta function, one gets one more segment - of width one - of analytic continuation for the Riemann zeta function."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I think I may have a solution, though it isn't pretty.

We can write $ \zeta (x) $ as:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac {1}{n^x}}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{e^{-x \ln (n)}}  $$
The expansion of $e^x$ is:
$$ e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {x^k}{k!}$$ 
Similarly the expansion of ${e^{-x \ln (n)}}$ is:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac {1}{n^x}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{e^{-x \ln (n)}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \frac {(-x)^k(\ln (n))^k}{k!} \right) \right) $$

Integrating the expression:
$$\int \left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \frac {(-x)^k(\ln (n))^k}{k!} \right) \right)\right)dx= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \frac {(-1)^k(x)^{k+1}(\ln (n))^k}{(k+1)k!} \right) \right)$$

> $$\therefore~ \int\zeta (x)dx=\int \left (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac {1}{n^x}} \right) dx=  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \frac {(-1)^k(x)^{k+1}(\ln (n))^k}{(k+1)k!} \right) \right)$$

Comment: Why to expand $e^{-x \log n}$? You can compute the integral directly according to Paul's comment: $$ \int e^{-x \log n} \,dx = -\dfrac{e^{-x \log n}}{\log n}+c, $$ for $n > 1$.

Answer (score 4):

[Rough Calculation] You may take it as an answer. I have been calculating the integration in the usual way, assuming $x$ to be **real**. $C$ is arbitrary constant.

$\displaystyle \int \zeta(x)dx=x-(\frac{1}{2^x\log 2}+\frac{1}{3^x\log 3}+\dots)+C$

Now, I claim that the infinite sum converges.

Since, for all $n>1$ and $x>1$ we have $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n^x}>\frac{1}{n^x\log n}$ summing over $n=2$ to $\infty$ we get,

$$\zeta(x)-1>\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^x\log n}$$ [I have not used weak inequality as I have not worked on the fact that when they will be equal]

The convergence is followed by the comparison test. As an overview we can say, $$\int\zeta(x)dx>x-1+\zeta(x)$$

Hope this works.